# Windows - Alternatives for Remote Desktop Locally

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm facing an issue that has become greater considering the working from home life. I have several PC's: my personal computer, my work computer, and another computer to work on a specific client's work. In the past, in a case like this, I would use my personal computer as the main PC and have two remote desktop sessions running. Everything could be easily accessible, only one set of cables needed, no docks required etc.

However, as expected, these 2 work laptops are now fully locked down by the respective IT orgs. No remote desktop access over LAN (I won't even mention any over the internet access for obvious reasons). Is there any way to emulate the setup I used to have? Or am I forced to constantly fumble with cables and docks, swivel back and forth between laptops, or remote desktop into my personal PC but that is only a partial fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VNC is a popular alternative to Remote Desktop.  It has to be installed on the machine though, so if you are locked out from that, you're out of luck.

Otherwise: https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/

Comment: Thanks Dave, I can use TightVNC to access the other laptops.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a KVM switch, use the same monitor/keyboard/mouse for all your devices.